# Cluster on two features and plot results

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have two dense matrix's (`title` and `para`). I wish to cluster them using an affinity propagation algorithm and then plot the clusters.

I have written the following code, which clusters based on one feature. How can I adapt this to cluster on both features and then plot the results?

```
import os
import time
import string
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

#from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

#Opens and stores preprocessed data.
filepath = '...'
with open((filepath + 'para.dat'), 'rb') as infile:
    para = pickle.load(infile)
with open(filepath + 'title.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    title = pickle.load(infile)
with open(filepath + 'y.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    y = pickle.load(infile)

af = AffinityPropagation().fit(para)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_
n_clusters_= len(cluster_centers_indices)
```

This is a part of an active learning approach where I am using this to implement query by clustering, whereby the entire data set is clustered and the centroids of the clusters form the training dataset producing a training dataset representative of the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many way to do so (but of course only a finite number of outcomes), so you need to be more precise on what the optimum outcome is.

For example, you can apply affinity propagation onto

```
alpha * para + (1 - alpha) * title
```

Comment: In this case, they are not equally weighted?

Comment: They probably cannot be compared, so even if you would set alpha to 0.5, they would not have equal influence.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is combine the arrays that you have into one big array so that they can all be clustered together one way that you can do that is by using the numphy append library **Exzample:**

```
X = np.append(title, para, axis =0)
af = AffinityPropagation().fit(X)
```

Now that they are combined they can be clustered to find the centers of them combined.